# Is this a case of overfitting? CNN Image classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

Pardon me if this question is considered off-topic or just generally a bad question, I am new to Computer Vision and CNNs in general.

I have 3440 images in total, for a total of 10 classes.

85 images per column of each row:

[image: 85 images per column of each row]

Because there are only 3440 images in my dataset, I used data augmentation to increase my dataset to 34400 images. (augment 10 times per image)

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator( 
       rescale = 1./255,
       rotation_range = 20, 
       width_shift_range = 0.10,
       height_shift_range = 0.10,
       zoom_range= 0.05
       )
```

This is the model that I used for both instances. (once with augmentation, once without)

```
model = Sequential() 

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape = (50, 50, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 2 hidden layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

# The output layer with 10 neurons, for 10 classes
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# Compiling the model using some basic parameters
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
              ,optimizer="adam"
              ,metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I was able to increase my accuracy from ~90%(no augmentation) to ~97%(with augmentation), however the difference between training accuracy and validation accuracy remains similar.

Graph with data augmentation:

[image: Graph with data augmentation]

I have read that non converging training and validation accuracies/loss with a big difference is a sign of overfitting.

Is this the case for my CNN model? What else can I do to improve my model?

The full codes can be found on my github

https://github.com/jwngo/SimpleImageClassifier

Thank you everyone, I appreciate your time.

EDIT: 
For the augmentated dataset, Training set is 29355 images, Validation set is 7331 images. The difference between accuracy is 0.9972(training) vs 0.9750(validation), difference in loss is 0.0102(training) vs 0.1245(validation)

The validation images have also been augmented, which I will change to only use non-augmented images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some regularizations (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/fundamentals-deep-learning-regularization-techniques/) e.g. dropout. What is the difference between training and validation accuracy? How large is the validation set?

Comment: Training set is 29355 images, Validation set is 7331 images.
The difference between accuracy is 0.9972 vs 0.9750, difference is loss is 0.0102 vs 0.1245

Comment: I think that the better approach is to create validation set before augmentation especially when you want to compare it later with the results for data without augmentation at all.

Comment: The 'problem' i'm having is that the shape of the graphs are almost identical between the augmented and un-augmented dataset. Are the training and validation accuracy and loss always supposed to converge?

Comment: I will try to do the validation set before augmentation as you suggest, but this will cause the validation set to be very small (maybe 960) compared to the test set. (>20,000) Will this be a problem?

Comment: 'The 'problem' i'm having is that the shape of the graphs are almost identical between the augmented and un-augmented dataset' -> This shows that augmentation made a profit, but model is still a little overfited. You can try to use some regulatization.